# JVM when deployed web service & web portal on same tomcat but different port

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6, tomcat7

When we deploy some web portal on say port 8080 on tomcat server & on another port say 8050 another web service on the same tomcat6 server (through server.xml changes), does portal & web service share the same JVM????

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes all webapps share the same JVM. Check out this answer for more info:

[tomcat isolate webapps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474840/tomcat-isolate-webapps)